# How to loop through a string n times until it gets equal to the original string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have few strings on which I need to loop and perform some operations such that I get back the original string after certain iterations.

For example in string `"1010"`, on each iteration, I need to move the the front characters based on iteration number

```
First iteration (1 iteration):  0101   (moved 1 character from front)
Second iteration (2 iteration): 0101   (moved 2 characters from front)
Third iteration (3 iteration):  1010   (moved 3 characters from front)
```

So I get back the original string

But for a string like `"1001"`, it will take 7 iterations

```
First iteration (1 iteration): 0011   (moved 1 character from front)
Second iteration (2 iteration): 1100   (moved 2 characters from front)
Third iteration (3 iteration): 0110   (moved 3 characters from front)
Fourth iteration (4 iteration): 0110   (moved 4 characters from front)
Fifth iteration (5 iteration): 1100   (moved 5 characters from front)
Sixth iteration (6 iteration): 0011   (moved 6 characters from front)
Seventh iteration (7 iteration): 1001   (moved 7 characters from front)
```

Here is my code below

```
string_list = ["1010", "1001"]

for i in string_list:
    print("i",i)
    t = 1
    print("starting t",t)
    new_string = i
    for j in i:
        num_letter = new_string[:t]
        print("num_letter", num_letter)
        new_string = new_string[t:] + num_letter
        print("intermediate new string",new_string)
        if new_string == i:
            print("no of iterations until same string occurs", t)
            break
        else:
            t += 1
            print("t",t)
```

Here for the first string, I get no of iterations to be `3` which is correct. But for the second string, it stops at the fifth iteration since the string's length is completely covered.

How do I ensure it keeps looping through the string untill I get back a string which is identical to the original string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `while` loop, iterate until same string occurs and do the slicing with `i % len(s)`, where `i` is the current iteration and `s` is the current string:

### Code

```python
string_list = ["1010", "1001"]

for s in string_list:
    i = 1
    curr_s = s

    print("starting t", s)

    while True:
        k = i % len(s)
        new_s = curr_s[k:] + curr_s[:k]

        print("intermediate new string",new_s)

        if new_s == s:
            print("no of iterations until same string occurs", i)
            break

        i += 1
        curr_s = new_s
```

### Output

[image]